# Selection service gives the selection from original window instead of new window when used in conjunction with IHandler. eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an eclipse rcp application in which I have defined a key binding (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>) which processes the current selection in a tree view.

This is working as expected but whenever I open a new window using `ActionFactory.OPEN_NEW_WINDOW.create(window)`, the key binding still works but it gets the selection from original window instead of newly opened window.

Any one know how to solve this problem?

**IHandler Implementation:**

```
public class MyHandler extends AbstractHandler{
    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        ISelection selection = HandlerUtil.getCurrentSelection(event);
        processCurrentSelection(selection);     
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which window is active when you use the key binding? The original window or the new window?

Comment: It is the new window active when I use the key binding. I literally click on the tree view in the new window to select an entry in the tree structure and invoke key binding.

Comment: In this case, it sounds like an bug... Do you have any code to illustrate the problem?

Comment: Hey I just created a new sample app and it is working properly. I figured out the issue. I was using the wrong handler in defaultHandler. Anyway thanks for your help.